# Can't access sub menu using webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can't access submenu eventhough i was able to hover over the parent menu and this is happening only for the site:

upon login need to access Candidates under Recruitment

http://www.livetech.co.in/hrms/symfony/web/index.php/auth/login

code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.annotations.*;

 public class Mouseover {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.navigate().to("http://www.livetech.co.in/hrms/symfony/web/index.php  /auth/login");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.name("txtUsername")).sendKeys("selenium");
    driver.findElement(By.name("txtPassword")).sendKeys("selenium");
    driver.findElement(By.name("Submit")).click();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Actions action=new Actions(driver);

       action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='menu_recruitment_viewRecruitmentModule']/b"))).click();

    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li/a")).click();
    System.out.println("executed");


}
```

}

can anyone help.
Regards,
Ram.

Comment: It seems you have been taking training from above mentioned website, why dont you ask it to your trainers?

Comment: first of all remove `.` from all the xpaths and give a try. The correct xpath : `//*[@id='menu_recruitment_viewRecruitmentModule']/b`

Comment: My trainer got a job offer and left to U.S. and his successor is not upto the mark.I tried . Can you help me with an answer.

Comment: Have a read through this: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using incorrect `Xpath`. Remove `.` . In your case it should start from `//`. `//*[@id='menu_recruitment_viewRecruitmentModule']/b`

Secondly if your motive is to reach to `Candidates` tab then directly click on `Recruitment`. It will solve your purpose.

Finally if you want to use mouse hover then you can easily implement it, but I suggest not to do it because you have easy way to do it.

Last call is always your

Thanks

Comment: :Hey!Used firepath to generate xpath,that is why the path is different than the relative path.But, i took your advice and changed the path(Used selenium ide to make sure the path is correct) and i also used click(). still doesn't work.Updated the code.

Comment: This code will do what you want`  driver.navigate().to("http://www.livetech.co.in/hrms/symfony/web/index.php/auth/login");
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.findElement(By.name("txtUsername")).sendKeys("selenium");
      driver.findElement(By.name("txtPassword")).sendKeys("selenium");
      driver.findElement(By.name("Submit")).click();

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu_recruitment_viewRecruitmentModule']/b")).click(); `

Comment: You helped me with same problem yesterday,i am trying to understand why mouse over is not working for this site alone.I understand we can access the menu and submenu directly.But, how to access them using mouseover. Thanks man